# Most efficient way to rule out classes from an interface's method

Tags: java

Up to this point, I have used the following code to restrict the application of some methods to instances of certain classes. For instance, using `ItemListener`, but this could be applied to many things,

```
public class mListener implements ItemListener {
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {

        if (!(e.getItemSelectable instanceof JCheckBox)) { //again, JCheckBox was chosen arbirtarily
            System.err.println("mListener can only be applied to a JCheckBox");
            return;
        }

    }
}
```

However, in a few places on the Oracle Java tutorials, I have seen the following code

```
public class mListener implements ItemListener {
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
        JCheckBox box = null;

        try {
            box = (JCheckBox) e.getItemSelectable();
        } catch (ClassCastException ex) {
            System.err.println("mListener can only be applied to a JCheckBox");
            return;
        }

    }
}
```

Which is the best way to lock out classes that you don't want a method applied to? This is especially the case with implementing interfaces, where the parameter can't be changed.

Comment: What's the actual goal? It's not like the JVM randomly applies listeners to arbitrary elements--are you trying to keep yourself from making mistakes? Is this in lieu of specs/tests?

Comment: sorry, posted before I was done typing

Comment: Which is most *efficient*? Anything not using exceptions.

Comment: @Dave Why would exceptions be a bad idea?

Comment: @gobernador Because they're slow--you said "efficient", and didn't specify in what sense.

Comment: @Dave I suppose I didn't mean "efficient". I've edited my question to say "best". I mean, given the choice between the two, which should I choose?

Comment: @gobernador I'd use an exception, which as Jon mentions, doesn't need to be caught explicitly. It's an exceptional situation--it should *never* happen, because it means the *developer* did something wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In both cases, this is a *programming error*. The listener is being added inappropriately. The correct response for this is almost certainly not just printing out a message where it will probably never be seen - it's an exception.

Simply casting will give you that exception without any work on your part, so just cast unconditionally, and don't try to cover up programming errors.

Answer (score 3):

The second version is evil, as it uses exceptions for flow control. Read [Effective Java by Joshua Bloch](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/effective/) to learn why that is bad (Item 57: "Use exceptions only for exceptional conditions").

Comment: I'm not sure I'd call that flow control--it's basically an assertion that shouldn't be visible in deployed code since it's a source-level problem.

Comment: @DaveNewton Then why not go for `assert e.getItemSelectable() instanceof JCheckBox`?

Comment: @isbadawi I don't know--ask the OP. I just don't consider this flow control, because it's a programming error, not a logic error.

Comment: I feel like using `assert` would be bad because what about times when you don't want the code to break down, but the user needs to be notified that something shouldn't be applied to, say, a `JRadioButton` instead

Comment: @gobernador The *user* shouldn't be notified of that--it's a development-level error that shouldn't be coded in the first place, and it should be caught before deployment.

Answer (score 0):

The answer may be this: catching a `ClassCastException` allows `e` to be any subclass of `JCheckBox`, whereas using instanceof restricts it solely to a `JCheckBox`.